# At the end of the 2017 Developer Survey, is the link we paste to our Profile or Activity tab?

Tags: support, survey-2017

The provided link takes me to "Activity" but the question says profile. Which one should I enter?

Comment: Semantically it's two tabs on the same page. So either's fine. Note how it's implemented using a query string, but the base URL is the same.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Doesn't matter. As long as it has your user ID in it (rather than... `/users/current`) it'll work.